how can i count paid time off entries on multiple calendars?
I have a paid time off tracker. Each employee has their own calendar year on one sheet. The month "boxes" are small. 7 columns, 6 rows. The data inside those cells is just text with each numerical day.
For each employee I put in their sick days and vacation days, by noting either "S" or "V', sometimes with a dash and a number next to that if its a partial day.
I want there to be a "total" calendar at the top so that I can see on Feb 23rd, 2 employees took vacation time.
I don't need to specify sick or vaca here, just a count of the people out of the office. I'm unsure of the best way to do this?

In another sheet, I put all the days of the year in one column.
Using the first employee, I used this formula and then painstakingly went through to adjust the cell refernces.
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("S",'2024 PTO Tracker by LeaveBoard'!K$18)),"sick",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("V",'2024 PTO Tracker by LeaveBoard'!K$18)),"vaca", " x"))

I can't do that for everyone. It just takes too much time. Is there a way to copy that formula to the next cell/column over and instead of changing each reference cell, just do a blanket command to do the calculation for 10 rows further down form the reference?
Or is there a better way to count it from the calendar page?

Do you need the number of sick days/vacation days, or do you need to have the dates themselves? If the former, something like =COUNTIF(A1:G6,"S")` would work

If you are trying to count the number of employees who are not there on a given day? This might be easier if you kept the same calendar format for all sheets, including the totals sheet (i.e. either all sheets are two columns or they are all month boxes).

@h.a.s ,, since U have separate calendar for each employee in that case at the bottom of each month's calendar better U COUNT Holidays , Sick Leave and others that will lead you to get the final picture of each employee throughout the year !

you can use a fomula like this to make it easier to replicate and maintain:
=LET(data,VSTACK(TOCOL(B4:H8),TOCOL(J4:P8)),FILTER(data,data<>""))

